# swiftmailer failed to authenticate on smtp server with username using 2 possible authenticators in amazon ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Amazon SES to send mail.But when i am using that SMTP credential in my swift mailer i am getting the error like.

failed to authenticate on smtp server with username using 2 possible authenticators

My logs file looks like below

ERROR - 2017-02-26T13:38:14-05:00 - exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXXXXXX" using 2 possible authenticators' in /var/www/html/directus/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:181

My configuration file looks

```
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'from' => 'test@example.com',
    'host' => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'port' => '25',
    'encryption' => 'tls',
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Team, 
 Finally found the solution. To make work we need to do 2 things.
1. Go to the location where directus installed in my case (/var/www/html/directus).run the below mentioned 3 command.

($ cd  /var/www/html/directus)
($ git checkout development)
($ git pull origin development)

2. Update the configuration.php file as below.
'mail' => [       
'transport' => 'smtp', 
'from' => 'test@example.com',  'host' => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
 'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
 'port' => '25',  
 'encryption' => 'tls'
  ],